# JavaScript indexof Doubts

Tags: javascript

In the following statement, if any part of string "mypage" matches with user input then Random Number (Greater than 0) is displayed, I want to know if there's any pattern how Random number is Generated?

```
var a=this.toString().indexOf("mypage");
```

Comment: What random number? How is it related to the `indexOf`? Your question makes zero sense, sorry.

Comment: @ShadowWizard When I use alert(a) for displaying value, if any part of string "mypage" matches with user input then a Random Number is displayed. I just wanna know if there's any pattern of number generation or it generates simply any value > 0

Comment: The `indexOf()` function returns a number, not a boolean.

Comment: FYI, it's "questions", not "doubts"

Comment: It's not random. It's the index of the first occurrence inside string. As the method name hint: **index** **Of**. I really advice you to learn the basics of JavaScript before posting here, having too many downvotes will cause you to get blocked from asking new questions eventually.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a random number, that's the index of the first character that matches the pattern passed to `indexOf` starting at 0, if it's less than 0 then the pattern was not found. So in your example the number returned from `indexOf` is the index of `m` from `mypage`

Answer (score 0):

That's not a random number, that's where in `a` `"mypage"` is found... isn't it?

Comment: No, it's where `m` is. `indexOf` always returns the index of the first character if the pattern is found.